# Jupyter Notebook python/ Why is this being printed?

Tags: python

[image]

1. Why is out[2] being tagged on the 2nd "Hello World"?
2. Why is the second "Hello World" being printed? I think it should be commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `Hello World` is the effect of your `print` statement.
`Out[2]` (more generally `Out[n]`) shows the result of the 2nd (more generally nth) execution you requested. In this case the result of the last line of `In [2]` which is just the string `"Hello World"`.